# ember simple auth: redirecting to previous route after login

Tags: authentication, ember.js, ember-simple-auth

My site has numerous pages that do not require login, and a few that do, and ember-simple-auth works great when transitioning to those pages that require authentication. When I am on a page that does not require authentication, and I attempt to log in, I am transitioned to whatever is set up for `routeAfterAuthentication`.

Unfortunately, what I really want is that if I am on a page that does not require authentication, for example, `/posts/1234` and I authenticate, I return to `posts/1234`. How can this be accomplished?

I've combed through the `ember-simple-auth` code for `ApplicationRouteMixin` for a suitable way to override `sessionAuthenticated`, but still I don't know of a way to inform the resulting application route as to what route to return to, or the params that route should be given.

Answer (score 0):

The EmberJS router holds information about where the user has been, so just add this into your routes/application.js file in the actions object:

```
sessionAuthenticationSucceeded: function() {
  this.transitionTo(
    this.controllerFor('application').get('previousRouteName')
  );
}
```

This probably could be documented better by the ember-simple-auth folks.

Answer (score 0):

My application does this by default, is this what your authenticated route looks like?

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {});
```

Comment: I believe I mentioned that all the AuthenticatedRoute(s) work just as I would like. The issue is with the routes that do not need authentication. When I use the login flow to login from these pages, I am redirected elsewhere, and can't automatically go back to the page where the login flow started.

Comment: Sorry, missed that important aspect.